# How do I find the best, worst and average result in a list?

Tags: python, list, file

I have an assignment where I have to use a file which has names and results of their achievements. I have managed to do part one which is to split the file so name and all the results end up on different rows. I now have to find the best, worst and average time for each person. I am stuck and I don't know how to proceed. I'll write the whole assignment underneath. I am currently stuck at number 2.

> In a file "Race_results.txt" the results have been collected from a number of races for a number (20 pcs.)
> clubmates running 100 meters. The result is saved with one row per participant there
> the name, e.g. "Rune Robertsson" is first followed by 10 pcs. results. The result may look like '10.74'
> or '11.3'.
>
> In this lab you will write a program that reads in data from the file and processes this data.
>
> What you have to do is:
>
> 1. Load data from the file for each participant and then split this data so that it is saved
>    in a list. In first and second position
>    the name will then be followed by a number (10) of positions with results.
> 2. For each participant; find out:  
>    a. the best time  
>    b. the worst time  
>    c. the mean of the ten results (mean_of_times)
> 3. For each participant; sort the times so that the best time is first and the worst last.
> 4. Print on the screen (for each participant, incl. appropriate prompt text):  
>    a. On row 1: names and times sorted from best to worst  
>    b. On line 2: "best time", "best time" and "average_of_the_times".  
>    c. Blank line between participants, i.e. the third line becomes a blank line**

For question 1.

```
lst=[]
person=[]
with open("Race_results.txt")  as fh:
  for line in fh:
    for word in line.split():
      print(word)
```

I thought of separating the numbers and the letters in the list so I can later hopefully easier find the best, worst and average results.

I tried something like this but I have no idea if this is something useful for me, I saw this in a different question but I don't think this could apply for me.

```
name=[e for e in word if not e.isfloat()]
numbers=[float(e)for e in line if e.isfloat()]
```

or

```
if word.isfloat():
      person.append(word)
```

I might be going on the wrong path here and would need some guidance. I'm happy for any kind of help.

Comment: post at least a testable fragment of `"Race_results.txt"` and expected format of the final output

Comment: Use a slice to get the results: `results = list(map(float, line.split()[2:]))`

Comment: You don't need `isfloat()`. The instructions specifically say that the first two elements are the name, the rest are results. `name = " ".join(line.split()[:2])`

Comment: I couldn't edit the text for some reason so ill put part of the file here.
Erik Eriksson 11.47 12.7 10.98 12.04 12.0 12.43 10.47 11.82 10.91 10.37
Anna Andersson 10.02 11.23 13.79 12.44 12.56 11.12 12.68 10.53 13.82 10.26
Olle Olsson 13.45 10.55 12.51 14.29 14.09 10.3 11.8 14.28 13.17 14.06
Eva Enoksson 13.09 14.05 12.47 13.45 11.33 14.91 12.56 10.23 10.56 10.86
Sven Svensson 12.99 12.79 11.4 10.6 12.94 10.02 11.96 14.2 12.35 13.34
Robin Robinsson 14.93 14.92 12.41 14.83 13.77 12.77 10.4 11.76 11.36 11.64
Stina Svensson 13.1 12.32 11.91 10.11 11.27 13.86 11.91 10.83 11.14 11.68

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your code until the part where you got stuck, I hope this helps!

```
# Question 1
parsed = []
with open("Race_results.txt") as f_in:
  for line in f_in:
    parsed.append(line.split())

# Question 2 (first part)
for person in parsed:
    # Get the first and last name of the person.
    name = person[0] + " "+ person [1]
    # Remove the names from the list (first 2 items).
    times = person[2:]
    # Parse the times to floats.
    times = map(lambda time: float(time), times)
    # Convert the map object to a list.
    times = list(times)

    # Here goes the code to find best time, usw..
    print(f"{name} {times}")
```

Output:

```
Erik Eriksson [11.47, 12.7, 10.98, 12.04, 12.0, 12.43, 10.47, 11.82, 10.91, 10.37]
Anna Andersson [10.02, 11.23, 13.79, 12.44, 12.56, 11.12, 12.68, 10.53, 13.82, 10.26]
Olle Olsson [13.45, 10.55, 12.51, 14.29, 14.09, 10.3, 11.8, 14.28, 13.17, 14.06]
Eva Enoksson [13.09, 14.05, 12.47, 13.45, 11.33, 14.91, 12.56, 10.23, 10.56, 10.86]
Sven Svensson [12.99, 12.79, 11.4, 10.6, 12.94, 10.02, 11.96, 14.2, 12.35, 13.34]
Robin Robinsson [14.93, 14.92, 12.41, 14.83, 13.77, 12.77, 10.4, 11.76, 11.36, 11.64]
Stina Svensson [13.1, 12.32, 11.91, 10.11, 11.27, 13.86, 11.91, 10.83, 11.14, 11.68]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I just have a question is it possible to have a result per row? I mean. 
Erik Eriksson

[11.47,


 12.7,

 10.98,


 12.04,


 12.0,


 12.43,


 10.47,


 11.82,


 10.91,


 10.37]

Comment: @Lostcause i edited my answer, so that the results are printed in one line with a f-string. Is this what you meant, or do you want to put the results in a data-structure (like a dictionary or list)?